# Is there any way to hide panels in IntelliJ 9?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 9.0, is there any way to hide the panels on the sides and bottom?  Specifically, I'm trying to hide the Ant Build panel, since I don't use Ant and don't want to have these extra panels taking up space on my side and bottom bars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can permanently remove the Ant Build panel by disabling the plugin.  Go to Settings > Plugins and uncheck the "Enable" box next to Ant Support.

Comment: This, to me, is the dumbest 'feature' of IJ - not being able to remove the two extreme panels (Project/Structure & Ant/Maven) - Thanks for this. Aargh - I cant disable it as hybris Integration plugin - for some insane reason - is tied to this.

Answer (score 16):

CTRL-SHIFT-F12 maximizes the editor

Also, SHIFT-ESC closes the active panel

Comment: For me, in Win7, CTRL-SHIFT-F12 retains the extreme side panels (Project/Structure & Ant/Maven); while Shift+Esc does nada, as is that way for many

Comment: Shift+Esc worked for me 

Comment: Command + Shift + F12 for mac.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Tool Window Manager plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1489?pr=) to be able to disable tabs that you don't use.

Comment: That plugin's from 2007, really doubt it will work with intellij 14 or 15. Is there something more recent that does the same?

Answer (score 2):

For current IDEA version 2018.1 (and for many previous editions)

1. Right-click the tool window button you want to hide (in your case the Ant Build).
2. Choose Remove from Sidebar

More info:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html

Comment: This doesn't work, as the window button will re-appear when restarting the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You can also do Cmd + 4. This toggles the panel for testing.